# Standard Basis and Change of Basis Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the matrix of transformation $ \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ taking $v_1 = (1,2,3)^T$ to $w_1 = (1,0,0,2)^T$, $v_2 = (2,3,4)^T$ to $w_2 = (1,2,3,4)^T$ and $v_3 = (1,1,2)^T$ to $w_3 = (0,5,1,7)^T$ by first finding the change of basis matrix from the basis ${v_1,v_2,v_3}$ to the standard basis and then multiplying it by the matrix which takes the standard basis to $w_1, w_2$ and $ w_3,$ respectively. Explain why this gives you the right answer.

---

Just really not sure where to begin, other than by forming the 3x3 matrix out of $v_1, v_2$ and $v_3$.

Comment: That’s a good start. Now, what is this matrix that you’ve formed good for?

Comment: I'm not sure. You want the standard basis which is just the identity matrix $e$ for a square 3x3 matrix.

Comment: I’ll continue this back in your original question.